# What is the differences between to and = in set search_path?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have different schemas in my database like,

> public
>
> Hotel_Management
>
> Hospital_Management

My default schema is `Public`. So I try to change from default schema to another schema.
I know how to change the schema from one to another.

```
set search_path to Hotel_Management;
```

But my doubt is, What is the real difference between `to` and `=` in `set search_path`?.

For example:

```
Set search_path to Hotel_Management;
```

and

```
Set search_path = Hotel_Management;
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

If you look [at the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) one is the alternative to the other. `{ TO | = }` means either `TO` **or** `=`

The meaning of that is explained at the [start of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/notation.html)

> *and vertical lines `|` indicate that you must choose one alternative*

Comment: Nitpicking: "you must choose one alternative" does not mean they are equivalent. For example `{ timezone | LOCAL | DEFAULT }`, the 3 choices are not the same thing. But I agree that there is no difference in this case. If there was a difference between `TO` and `=`, it would have been explained in that page.